# ¿Cómo organizar mi portada en latex?

Tags: latex

Esta es mi portada en latex. Los autores y la fecha me aparecen duplicados en la parte superior e inferior de la página y solo los deseo en la parte inferior. Además tengo una página en blanco al inicio que deseo eliminar. Intenté con chatgpt pero no logré nada.

```
\title{Laboratorio 1 \\ Propiedades físicas de Magmas/Lavas}
\author{Samuel García \and Paul Forero \and Paula Lora \and Hugo Perlaza}
\date{Agosto 2023}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage} % Página de portada
    \centering % Centra todo el contenido de la página
    \vspace*{\fill} % Espacio vertical antes del título
    \maketitle % Título centrado
    \vspace*{\fill} % Espacio vertical antes del contenido inferior
   \begin{center}
       Universidad de Los Andes \\
       Samuel García \quad Paul Forero \quad Paula Lora \quad Hugo Perlaza \\
       Agosto 2023
   \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```